# Count records in query in groups based on column value

Tags: sql

Let's suppose a have a very simple query in SQL

```
SELECT Col1,Col2 From Table1
```

and it gives me result:

```
Col1  Col2
A     5
A     7
A     2
B     1
B     1
B     4
B     0
C     4
C     1
C     2
```

I want to count rows in groups made by Col1 and in order made by Col2. If values in Col2 for some rows in group are equal then they should have different numbers, as shown in example

So I want to have

```
Col1  Col2 Nr
A     5    2
A     7    3
A     2    1

B     0    1
B     1    2
B     1    3
B     4    4

C     4    3
C     1    1
C     2    2
```

Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database supports window functions, use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
select col1,col2,row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col2) as nr
from tablename
```

If your database doesn't support window functions, use

```
select col1,col2,
(select count(*)+1 from tablename t1 where t1.col1=t.col1 and t1.col2<t.col2) as nr
from tablename t
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. I'm using Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` window function:

```
SELECT   col1,
         col2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 ASC) AS Nr
FROM     table1
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```